# String manipulation of html output while preserving tags

Tags: html, ruby, string, nokogiri

I'd like to do a simple split on `:` of an HTML string, while preserving the underlying HTML formatting.

Suppose I have data structured like so, rendered in HTML:

> Data for **column a: data** for column b

But the underlying HTML might be

```
<p>Data for <span style="font-weight: bold">column a: data</span> for column b</p>
```

And my output would preferably be

```
cola = '<p>Data for <span style="font-weight: bold">column a</span></p>'
colb = '<p><span style="font-weight: bold">data</span> for column b</p>'
```

or more complicated examples.

*I am using Ruby & Nokogiri.*

Comment: Don't get your need..can you bit a more specific ? Where `:` is gone from here `<span style="font-weight: bold">HTML</span>` ?

Comment: Your example doesnt make sense.  Why do you even care about splitting on the colon when all you are doing is adding a comma after the closing `</span>` tag?

Comment: I have updated the text with an example that shows more what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment '<p>Data for <span style="font-weight: bold">column a: data</span> for column b</p>'

a, b = doc.css('span').text.split ':'

cola = '<p>Data for <span style="font-weight: bold">' + a + '</span></p>'
colb = '<p><span style="font-weight: bold">' + b + '</span> for column b</p>'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only works for the example given and not the general case.

Comment: Use `doc.at('p').children[0].text`, `doc.at('p').children[2].text` for text

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually solved this problem. [My solution on Github](https://github.com/fletchermoore/html-splitter/blob/master/splitter.rb)

Basically, I did a preorder traversal of the Nokogiri fragment, searching only text nodes until I found my delimiter. Once found, I split the text node like you would any string. Then I removed all the nodes subsequently encountered during the preorder traversal. This clears the "right side".

Then I followed with a postorder traversal of the same initial Nokogiri fragment, as above, deleting all nodes until I encountered a text node containing my delimiter. This clears the "left side"